# Unlock iPad without FaceID

Tags: ipad, unlock, face-id

With FaceID enabled sometimes my iPad allows me to unlock it with the passcode.

What finger gesture can I use to force a passcode entry instead like when FaceID does not work. I want to force the iPad to accept (allow me) to enter my passcode?

This is not a face mask problem.

There are times when I am just done with the FaceID nonsense and I want to enter the pass phrase but cannot get the iPad to give me that option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ipad use keyboard to unlock instead of faceid](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461369/ipad-use-keyboard-to-unlock-instead-of-faceid)

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, edit the original to address the close reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the power button on the iPad until you see the “slide to turn off”.  Don’t turn it off. Instead press “Cancel”

You are now forced to enter your passcode and touchID and FaceID aren’t enabled again until you enter the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try just swiping from the bottom. Then you can enter the passcode.

Comment: Wouldn’t that just use FaceID by default?  What causes the pass code to enable by swiping up?

Comment: because various things inwearvand i believe lighting conditions. i also have a very very large bushy beard my experience with facial recognition is beards cause problems.

Comment: as for swiping up all i get is the text faceid